# how to get html text before its load on page using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to alert text before its load on page.

```
var jaw='<div id="text">hii</div>';
alert($('#text').text())
$('body').append(jaw)
```

Comment: perhaps you should explain in detail what you are attempting to do. What you demonstrate here is illogical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $jaw = $('<div id="testing">this is stuff <div id="text">hii</div></div>');
alert($jaw.find('#text').html());
$jaw.appendTo(document.body);
```

You already have a string literal, though, so given the code you have above you could simply do `alert(text)`.

Note that `html()` will return inner html. `text()` will return inner text.  If you want outerHTML search for outerHTML solutions for jQuery.  That's another topic.

EDIT: Added JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/FYbeH/3/

Comment: in your example it is alerting whole html but i want to get html of perticuler id, see my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FYbeH/1/

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  The fiddle you presented is NOT my code, nor does it alert anything (thus it is not doing what he is asking).  My code, when fiddled, works.  http://jsfiddle.net/FYbeH/2/ but, as I explained, it is doing inner HTML and not outer, of which I also presented a solution for -- pick your favorite outerHTML solution for jquery and use it.  But it's the same otherwise.

Comment: In my fiddle I am appending two div i want get html of div which has id "text"

Comment: Update your question accordingly.  I've updated my answer - http://jsfiddle.net/FYbeH/3/

Comment: thanks now it is working, but more thing it is not working when "text" div outside the "werd" div and why we need to put html in $()

Comment: update the jsfiddle with your example and tell me what you're expecting vs what you're getting.

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/FYbeH/4/, it is alerting 'undefined' i want to alert '#text' html

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FYbeH/5/ I think you don't quite follow how it works.  When you let jquery create an element for you, it has to create *ONE* element.  So you need a fake parent/wrapper in order to get content from it.

Answer (score -1):

you can try with

```
         $(document).ready(function() {
              var jaw='<div id="text">hii</div>';
              $('body').append(jaw)
              alert($('#text').text())
          });
```

read jquery documentation .[ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: He wants to alert before adding it to the page.  This alertsa fter it is added.